# How to prevent JQTransform override Salesforce Global Search Field alignment?

Tags: community, jquery

I 'm facing this issue, the Search text not align well in the Search's field.

[image]

I am not sure where is the source code come from, what I understand it impossible to customize css for this search, but it seem that this Search field is mess up.

I check the code element in Chrome, and it is like below:

```
 <div class="searchBoxClearContainer">
<div class="jqTransformInputWrapper jqTransformSafari" style="width: 210px;">
<div class="jqTransformInputInner">
<div><input autocomplete="off" id="phSearchInput" maxlength="100" name="str" placeholder="Search..." size="20" title="Search..." type="text" value="" class="jqtranformdone jqTransformInput" style="width: 226px;" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
```

I suspect it might due to this code

```
 <div class="jqTransformInputWrapper jqTransformSafari" style="width: 210px;">
    <div class="jqTransformInputInner">
```

But where should I remove this, because this is seem like Salesforce CSS?

---Edited---

I think I found the root cause in jquery.jqtransform.js script.

```
$input.addClass("jqTransformInput").wrap('<div class="jqTransformInputWrapper"><div class="jqTransformInputInner"><div></div></div></div>');
```

But any idea how to ensure this script not override Salesforce input?I read here ['Excluding inputs from jqTransform'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575824/excluding-inputs-from-jqtransform-plugin)  , but in this case Standard Salesforce Search being overriden so we cannot set the class for it.

Comment: Are you seeing this on all pages or just on Visualforce pages?

Comment: Not all pages, but only certain Visualforce page.

Comment: It sounds like you must have something in the CSS of your Visualforce pages that is causing issues. Are you by chance using Bootstrap in your Visualforce pages?

Comment: Yes, thanks for fast reply.I am using bootstrap but when I comments the bootstrap script, the field still not change.Perhaps maybe due to other script, I will comment it out by one to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is an ideal answer or not but somehow it fixed my issue.I noticed that in jqtransform.js contain this script

```
$input.addClass("jqTransformInput").wrap('<div class="jqTransformInputWrapper"><div class="jqTransformInputInner"><div></div></div></div>');
```

So in order to make sure it not override Global Search Input, I add this script

```
if(this.id=='phSearchInput') {return;}
```

Because phSearchInput is id of the Salesforce Global Search, so if it won't override this input.In case you have other answer let me know.

Thanks.